How can we prove that an uncountable set is a disjoint union of an uncountable number of countable sets.
The difficulty seems to be that when I choose elements from the uncountable set, to form the uncountable number of countable sets, the process of choosing those elements seems to involve a countable number of steps. Since a countable number of countable sets is countable, I cannot complete the proof because I cannot use all the elements of the uncountable set.

You can just let each countable set consists of one single element (which is finite, hence countable).

You seem to have described exactly the situation here.  You might consider the partially ordered set of subsets of your initial uncountable set...  (... because you want something like transfinite induction and vigorously repeated application of the axiom of dependent choice).

You should clarify your notion of countable. Are you allowing finite sets (singletons, say) to be countable?  Or did you mean to say "countably infinite"?

Maybe you should also clarify whether you want the "uncountable" set to have the same cardinality as the "uncountable" family of disjoint countable sets. (I suppose you do.)

The original uncountable set I want to have the cardinality of the continuum. Then, I want to prove that it is a disjoint union of an uncountable number of countably infinite sets, again where "uncountable" means the cardinality of the continuum (which I think it must have, or else the disjoint union would have cardinality greater than the cardinality of the continuum.)

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be an uncountable set. This means that it has an uncountable quantity of elements. Then
\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{X} = \bigcup_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \{x\}
\end{equation*}
represents $\mathcal{X}$ as a disjoint union of an uncountable number of countable sets.

This shows that an uncountable set can be an uncountable disjoint union of finite sets. It is not clear from the post that this proves the assertion. It seems unlikely that @Bob would have missed such an obvious proof.
